# resizing the canvas dimensions and size of a bitmap file

Tags: android, android-file, android-bitmap

My application is attempting to resize a PNG file from external storage that is rectangular: *(1000 w x 2000 h for example)*

The goal is to turn it into a a 256 x 256 image, by adding blank space on both sides of the image so that it is now 2000 x 2000 and then scale it down to 256x256 thus making it square without stretching the original image.

I thought i could be clever and use `ImageView` to do this and add a preview of the image scaled to the screen but i am crashing with a nullpointer....

**My resize method**

```
private void  resizeImage(String fileName){
        ImageView tempImageView = new ImageView(this);
        tempImageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        tempImageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(256, 256));
        tempImageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getKingNozzleStorageDirectory()+fileName);
        tempImageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
        rootView.addView(tempImageView);
        tempImageView.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap resized_bm = tempImageView.getDrawingCache();

        FileOutputStream outStream;

        try {
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(getKingNozzleStorageDirectory() + "new"+fileName );

            try {
                resized_bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
                outStream.flush();
                outStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

**The Exception i am catching:**

> 06-03 08:43:50.006: W/System.err(3842): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   06-03 08:43:50.006: W/System.err(3842):   at
>   com.eliddell.kingnozzle.activities.KNDrawingActivity.resizeImage(KNDrawingActivity.java:285)
>   06-03 08:43:50.006: W/System.err(3842):   at
>   com.eliddell.kingnozzle.activities.KNDrawingActivity.onClick(KNDrawingActivity.java:223)
>   06-03 08:43:50.006: W/System.err(3842):   at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 06-03 08:43:50.006:
>   W/System.err(3842):   at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 06-03
>   08:43:50.006: W/System.err(3842):     at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 06-03
>   08:43:50.006: W/System.err(3842):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 06-03
>   08:43:50.006: W/System.err(3842):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 06-03 08:43:50.006:
>   W/System.err(3842):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 06-03
>   08:43:50.006: W/System.err(3842):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 06-03
>   08:43:50.006: W/System.err(3842):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 06-03 08:43:50.006:
>   W/System.err(3842):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   06-03 08:43:50.006: W/System.err(3842):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 06-03
>   08:43:50.006: W/System.err(3842):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

**If i comment out the following line**

```
resized_bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
```

it doesn't crash which leads me to believe the resize_bm is not being created?

```
Bitmap resized_bm = tempImageView.getDrawingCache();
```

Obviously there are probably other ways of achieving my canvas resizing, so those insights are of course welcome.. but anyone know what i am doing wrong?

I didn't see any native ways to add canvas padding to the width of a bitmap..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have not created `Bitmap` on this line:

```
Bitmap resized_bm = tempImageView.getDrawingCache();
```

You need to make more modification with your ImageView. Try this:

```
    tempImageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    // resize and create canvas
    tempImageView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(256, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(256, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
    tempImageView.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight()); 

    tempImageView.buildDrawingCache(true);
    final Bitmap resized_bm = tempImageView.getDrawingCache();
    tempImageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

**UPDATE:**

Why you don't use standard methods?

```
final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(256, 256, Config.ARGB_8888);
final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
final Bitmap tmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getKingNozzleStorageDirectory() + fileName);
final int width = (int) (1f * tmp.getWidth() / tmp.getHeight() * 256);
final int height = 256;
final Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tmp, width, height, false);
final int leftOffset = (bitmap.getWidth() - scaled.getWidth()) / 2;
final int topOffset = 0;
canvas.drawBitmap(scaled, leftOffset, topOffset, null);
```

**UPDATE2:**

If you want work with ImageView, It may be strange, but this code work for me:

```
final ImageView tempImageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
final Bitmap tmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
tempImageView.setImageBitmap(tmp);
tempImageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

// resize and create canvas
tempImageView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(256, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(256, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
tempImageView.layout(0, 0, tempImageView.getMeasuredWidth(), tempImageView.getMeasuredHeight()); 

tempImageView.buildDrawingCache(true);
final Bitmap resized_bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(tempImageView.getDrawingCache());
tempImageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Comment: curious, about to try this, but why do you set the drawing cache enable to false again?

Comment: For clearing drawing cache.
http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/View.html#setDrawingCacheEnabled(boolean)
It is a good way to clear it after you complete work with bitmap.

Comment: ok i tried this.. but still getting the same result..  its actually writing a file, its just empty..

Comment: final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(256, 256, null); throws a null pointer

Comment: Sorry, try to set Config.ARGB_8888 instead of null

Comment: Sorry for not whole checked code. I have another istake at line final int width = tmp.getWidth() / tmp.getHeight() * 256; I fix it and update my answer.

Comment: i think there was one more mistake though right?  drawBitmap(scaled... no?

Comment: Yep, you need to draw scaled bitmap on base bitmap of course